# Answer of Lagrange dual problem of $x^2+1$ in Boyd and Vandenberghe is wrong?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm new to convex optimization field and start to learn dual theory in Boyd and Vandenberghe's book and find my solution to the following problem is not the same as the answer given in the standard answer [here](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf).

The question is to find the dual problem of $$minimize\,x^2+1 \\s.t. (x-2)(x-4)\le0.$$ My method is as follows. The Lagrangian of the the primal problem is $L(x,\lambda)=x^2+1+\lambda(x-2)(x-4)$. The dual function $g(\lambda)$ then should be $\inf_{x\in D}L(x,\lambda)$ where $D$ is the feasible set which should be $[2,4]$. First derivative to $L(x,\lambda)$ w.r.t $x$ and set the equation to $0$ we should have $x=\frac{3\lambda}{1+\lambda}$. But we have $\lambda\ge0$, when $\lambda \in [0,2]$, we see that $\frac{3\lambda}{1+\lambda}$ does not lie in the feasible set, i.e., $x\in[2,4]$, so we should choose $g(\lambda)$ with $\lambda\in[0,2]$ to be $5$. As for $\lambda\in(5,+\infty)$, we simply replace $x=\frac{3\lambda}{1+\lambda}$ into $L(x,\lambda)$ to get $\frac{-9\lambda^2}{1+\lambda}+1+8\lambda$. So my final duality problem is:
$$
maximize\,\,g\left( \lambda \right) \begin{cases}
 5,\lambda \in \left[ 0,2 \right]\\
 \frac{-9\lambda ^2}{1+\lambda}+1+8,\lambda \in \left( 2,+\infty \right)\\
\end{cases}
\\
s.t. \lambda \ge 0
$$
The answer of Boyd in the link is:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\operatorname{maximize} & -9 \lambda^{2} /(1+\lambda)+1+8 \lambda \\
\text { subject to } & \lambda \geq 0 .
\end{array}
$$
Am I right?

Comment: $\mathcal{D}$ is the common domain of all the functions appearing in the primal formulation, not the feasible set. It would be very inconvenient if writing out the dual required knowing the primal feasible set in the first place.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Oops, thanks. Why do I have the memory that $\mathcal{D}$ is the feasible set...